# "Open for suggestions" VS "Open to suggestions"

Tags: prepositions

I wonder if it's grammatically correct to write: "We're open for your suggestions."

I know about the idiom: "open to something" but is it possible to use "for" instead of "to"? Or it is a mistake in any case...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using "for" here is perfectly grammatical, but not very idiomatic. It would probably have a slightly different implication: "We're open, so come in and give us your suggestions."